# Android app for fetching available seat info from a booking website

Tags: android

I am looking for creating an android app for fetching available seats from a bus ticket booking site. I am not adding the functionality to book tickets but the person using the app should be able to get seat and service availability. I want to know how to connect to the website in realtime and fetch info.  I know this is bit broad but can someone give me a rough idea or a link to a tutorial on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tutorial on how to get data from a server http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

What you are looking for is called a **Web Service**. Basically the data is stored in the server, and you retrieve it by GET request to the url www.mydomain.com/my_seats

Basically the website should present you the data either in **JSON** or **XML** format, so you get the data as showed in the tutorial and then parse it to variables.

Answer (score 1):

This question will likely be closed because no one can give a definite answer, and I can't add this as a comment because it's too long... but what you need to do is forget about your application first, and just get into Android Development in general. Otherwise, you're just going to confuse yourself.

Do you have any experience with Java? If not, start at the oracle documentation. If you do though, start right here: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html. Once you get the basics down and reproduce the basic Hello World app, learn how to use fragments, use intents etc etc, you'll have a good idea of where to begin for your bus app.

Then it'll be pretty straightforward to go about developing the Activities and your UI. You will also need to know how to communicate with the server to query for what data you need (the seat availability etc), which you'll find a lot of different resources on, but here's one place you can start:

http://osamashabrez.com/simple-client-server-communication-in-android/

Comment: Invincible +1 for good comment.

Comment: seems like a misunderstanding...edited the question.. I know java and android development in general and what i dont know is the server part

Comment: You have to think of the server you want to use first, then see how that works with Android.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it is too wide and general question, if you could split it to pieces, you would get something like this: connect to website(a lot of results on SO), use cookies (a lot of results on SO), parse date from response(a lot of results on SO), etc... Also! We would help you then, but only if the question is NOT DUPLICATE.

So... as I said, try to split your problem on smaller parts, work on them. When you finish try to join finished parts.

Maybe! The problem to create something like this might be big for you, but if you split it you will see that is wasn't so hard to archieve it.